# react-hot-loader not working properly with all urls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hot-loader

I have managed to get a basic setup with react-hot-loader working. It works fine for any url with a single `/` (like `localhost:8080/test`), but once I add another slash (for instance `localhost:8080/test/asd`) it does a refresh, rather than a proper hot update. The page still shows fine, it's only the hot loading part that is not as expected.

This is my setup: https://github.com/severisv/react-hot-loader-example

What is going on? Is there any way around this?

Comment: I think you should use react router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding publicPath to the output section of the webpack-config solved the issue:

```
output: {
    ...
    publicPath: '/'
},
```